# Getting a unique index in a list?

Tags: c#

The short and simple version is this: I have a database. I have a c# list that I use to interact with that database. Program starts, dump the data into the list, program ends, save it back into the database.

Here's my problem though: I need to make sure that one of my attributes in the list (id) is always unique when I create and remove list items. I was thinking maybe a list might have something similiar to a SQL auto-increment? Or perhaps just a numerical index of which item is in which location?

```
AddedDependents.Add(new Dependent
                   {
                       IsSpouse = isSpouse,
                       Id = /*unique id/*
                   });
```

Comment: Lists are ordered, and are indexed.  You could use the place in the list that they are at.  AddedDependents[0]...etc

Comment: Does your 'save to db' operation take in a list or one item? When you say 'remove', it is a 'soft' or 'hard' delete in the db?

Comment: The database is untouched until the list is finished, and then it is saved. All manipulation is done in the list, and then the database is deleted and re-created using the new list data

Comment: @StefanH Would that go something like, Add(new item), item.id = indexof(item)? I am not sure of the syntax for that.

Comment: When you save it back to the DB, you could loop through the list with a for loop, the counter of the for loop will be the index in the list, and is therefore unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the index of the list:

```
AddedDependents.Add(new Dependent
               {
                   IsSpouse = isSpouse,
                   Id = AddedDependents.Count
               });
```

Then the `Dependent` Id and list index are the same so it becomes trivial to get that `Dependent` from the list.

As mentioned in the comments, if you are likely to delete elements from this list then you can't just get the dependent via the Id, like `AddedDependents[dependent.Id]` but instead would need to iterate through the list:

```
AddedDependents.Where(d => d.Id == dependent.Id);
```

Comment: but what would happen when you remove an element?

Comment: This is what I had originally done, but the issue is this: if I have 3 entries with id 1, 2, 3, and I delete 2, and create a new one, that one also has id 3, giving me two with id = 3.

Comment: True, removing an element in this case is troublesome.  You wouldn't be able to just do `AddedDependents[dependent.Id]` but instead loop through the list to find the Id, which isn't so bad.

Answer (score 0):

How about generating a `Guid`?

E.g.

```
AddedDependents.Add(
    new Dependent
    {
        IsSpouse = isSpouse,
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
     });
```

Thus implies that your "Id" is a string, I could not read from your question whether this is possible or not.

Alternatively, do no make it a string, but let it be a `Guid` type, like:

```
AddedDependents.Add(
    new Dependent
    {
        IsSpouse = isSpouse,
        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
     });
```